# Объясните про область видимости и использование переменных

Tags: java

Здравствуйте.

В Java новичок и сталкиваюсь с этой ситуацией уже не первый раз, поэтому прошу - сильно не пинайте )).

Суть в чем: Есть некий "основной код" программы. В котором объявлена переменная

```
int N = 0;
```

Далее, по необходимости, приспичило мне сделать обработчик клика по кнопке в этом "основном коде" программы.

Вот я пишу (к примеру):

```
button.addClickHandler (new ClickHandler(){
@Override
public void onClick(ClickEvent event){
....
}
});
```

и внутри обработчика хочу присвоить переменной N какое либо значение (ну ведь бывает такое что надо?! ):

```
button.addClickHandler (new ClickHandler(){
@Override
public void onClick(ClickEvent event){
   N = 123;
}
});
```

Не даёт! Подчеркивает N красным и ошибка, что мол невозможно связать значение с этой переменной.

Объявление **N** через **final** не спасает ситуацию.

Поясните пожалуйста, как умные люди решают эту проблему?
Заранее благодарю

Comment: Пишут на Шарпе)))

Comment: Можно код класса (классов) где N и откуда пытаетесь её получить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видимость переменных/классов определяется модификаторами доступа (private, public etc), а также областями видимости внутри блоков кода, ограниченных фигурными скобками `{}`

В случае с последними переменная объявленная в к-л блоке кода, окружённая `{}` видна только внутри этого блока (за исключением случаев, когда это переменная класса, имеющая public или default(т.е. без модификаотора; видна в одном пакете) уровень доступа) и всех внутренних блоках.

Скорее всего, в вашем случае у вас ваша переменная `N` объявлена внутри к-л метода и, засим, не видна вне его, в других методах класса. Чтобы сделать эту переменную доступной во всех методах класса, вам надо поместить её в блок кода, содержащий все методы класса, т.е. в сам класс.

Примерный код:

```
public class Test
{
    int N = 1; //переменная уровня класса (поле класса); Видна во всех вложенных блоках кода, т.е. во всех методах класса


    public void someMethod()
    {
         int N2 = 1;
    }

    public void anotherMethod()
    {
         //N2 = 1; //ошибка компиляции - переменная N1 не видна из этого блока кода
         N = 2; //можно, т.к. переменнная объявлена в обрамляющем блоке кода и её тут видно
    }
}
```

Comment: Речь о переменной в замыкании. Объявляешь локальную переменную внутри блока (не класса) и внутри него же ещё какую-нибудь функцию. Доступ к переменной на чтение будет, а на запись джава не позволит. В вопросе же `button.addClickHandler (new ClickHandler(){`.

Comment: Так о чем и речь. Чтение без проблем. А записывать в N не даёт. Кстати N объявлена в одном public-методе класса. И в этом же методе есть обработчик клика. И проблем с видимостью нет. С записью проблемы.

Comment: @Vard32, если переменная ваша - поле класса, то запись в неё должна без проблем из любого места в классе происходить если она не final...

Comment: @Qwertiy, ну да, с локальной не выйдет - потому я и предлагаю перенести переменную на уровень класса - так с ней можно будет что угодно делать)

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Всё правильно. Только что проверил.

Comment: _"зачем такие сложности, если можно просто объявить переменную в классе (не методе класса) ?"_
Класс я мог и не объявлять, а использовать какой-нибудь имеющийся - просто не в курсе, есть ли в джаве что-то подходящее. По поводу использования поля - всё по обстоятельствам. Не всегда хорошо захламлять класс всяким мусором, который ему не нужен. А то можно было и все переменные глобальными сделать.

Comment: Согласен. Захламлять мусором вообще нехорошо. В коде я стараюсь избегать глобальных переменных. Но иногда, без них просто никак.

Answer (score 6):

Использовать вместо переменной `N` поле некоторого объекта. Джава не разрешает записывать в переменные, доступные из замыкания, поскольку замыкание осуществляется по значению, а не по ссылке.

Так сделать нельзя
http://ideone.com/4d8Seg

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.function.*;

class Ideone {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        int a = 9;

        Consumer<Integer> f = (Integer b) -> {
            System.out.println(a + b);
            // a = 3; // ERROR
        };

        f.accept(10);

        // a = 3; // ERROR
    }
}
```

Но вот так - можно
http://ideone.com/CkyIuK

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.function.*;

class Ideone {
    static class Wrapper {
        public Integer a;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Wrapper w = new Wrapper();
        w.a = 9;

        Consumer<Integer> f = (Integer b) -> {
            System.out.println(w.a + b);
            w.a = 7; // Allowed
        };

        f.accept(10);
        f.accept(10);
        w.a = 3; // Allowed
        f.accept(10);
    }
}
```

> Хм... А почему нельзя последнее присвоение в первом примере сделать?.. 0_о

Потому что замыкание в джаве делается по значению. В скоуп функции `f` попадает копия переменной `a`. Естественно, изменение переменной внути или снаружи `f` не скажется на второй копии. Поэтому решили, что изменять переменную нельзя нигде. Т. е. переменная должна быть `final`, однако это разрешено не писать, лишь бы она фактически являлась неизменяемой.

Кстати, в C# это решается при помощи автоматического помещения замыкаемых переменных в промежуточный объект. Соответственно, любое изменение полей этого объекта видимо в обоих местах.

В Си++ нужно явно указать, получит ли лямбда значение или ссылку. Этот подход неприменим в джаве и шарпе, поскольку функция может просуществовать дольше переменной в стеке - в таком случае ссылка на переменную станет некорректной и это непроверяемо. В плюсах, естественно, ответственность за такое действие на программисте.

Comment: Лично я не понял, что вы хотели сказать(

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, http://ideone.com/4d8Seg.

Comment: Это-то понятно... Видимо надо мне узнать что за зверь "замыкание")

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, дополнил ответ кодом.

Comment: Хм... А почему нельзя последнее присвоение в первом примере сделать?.. 0_о

Comment: Можно, только надо определиться: или делаем класс и там объявляем публичное поле. Или сразу - объявляем публичное поле (переменную) на уровне класса.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ответ дополнен.

Comment: @Qwertiy, я всё ещё не понимаю вторую ошибку в первом примере(. http://ideone.com/WShGeK

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, переменная используется в замыкании. Копия переменной. Если изменить её тут, в лямбде останется старое значение. Поэтому менять нельзя. Совсем нельзя.

Comment: @Qwertiy, т.е. если где-то в некоем анонимном классе использовать, то компилятор начинает дальнейшее использование запрещать?.. 0_о Жесть какая))) Мне сложно уловить чё за нах, но я вам верю, что оно так должно быть и это логично)

Comment: @Qwertiy, почитал про замыкания, перечитал ответ, стало понятнее)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, не дальнейшее, а любое. Это полноценный неявный `final`: http://ideone.com/vgLTzy При это чтение доступно везде, а запись - нигде.

Comment: Кстати, @ЮрийСПб, а я думал, ты джавист?

Comment: @Qwertiy, я самоучка) Когда с этой ситуацией впервые столкнулся я методом тыка выяснил, что чтоб ты с локальной переменной не делал, в замыкании ей ничего не присвоишь. И при этом, если это будет полем класса, то всё будет отлично работать. Запомнил и не стал вникать в детали, т.к. в тот момент ещё и про ссылки-значения ничего не знал и мне надо было лишь заставить какой-то костыль сделать то, что я от него хотел)))