# Java 8, Философия java, внутренние классы

Tags: java, ооп

Здравствуйте!
Почему код внизу не работает в java 7 (предупреждение компилятора), а в java 8 работает?

```
interface Destination{
    String readLabel();
}
public class Parcel9 {
    // Argument must be final to use inside
    // anonymous inner class:
    public Destination destination(String dest) {
        return new Destination() {
            private String label = dest;
            public String readLabel() { return label; }
        };
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parcel9 p = new Parcel9();
        Destination d = p.destination("Tasmania");
        System.out.println(d.readLabel());
    }
}
```

Comment: А какое предупреждение?

Comment: Variable 'dest' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final

Comment: @VladD, в тексте вопроса есть: _Argument must be final to use inside anonymous inner class:_

Comment: Ага, увидел. Хороший вопрос тогда.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

В 8 яве компилятор сам вычисляет, является ли использованная вами переменная фактически финальной (т.е. вы не пытаетесь ей что-то присвоить) и позволяет скомпилировать, неявно подставив `final`

В 7 яве такого механизма нет и вам надо объявить аргумент как `final` для того, чтобы код скомпилировался.

Comment: то есть если добавить в функцию присваивание параметру - то java8 так же ругнется?

Comment: @Grundy, как это не странно, но, похоже, так и [будет](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/541813/17609))